# HelpPage xml documentation when controllers or models in different assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Using the new webapi 2.1 bits. For some reason when I open the help page no description details appear for any properties e.g.

```
/// <summary>
/// Some summary that shows correct
/// </summary>
[DataContract]
public class MyClass
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Display something.....
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "Great")]
    public string MyGreatProperty { get; set; }
```

When I open the help page I can see the summary "Some summary that shows correct" however for the properties of this model none of the summaries are showing up.

Does webapi 2 not support descriptions on a property?

Comment: Have you upgraded the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage` nuget package to `5.1`?

Comment: Yes fully upgraded to 5.1

Comment: I am unable to repro the issue. Can you share how the file `HelpPageConfig.cs` under `Areas\HelpPage\App_Start` folder looks like and also the controller's action on which you are using this model `MyClass`?

Comment: Kiran the easiest way to reproduce the issue is to create a solution containing a webapi project and a class library. Use the class library as your models... similar to the above code and setup the webapi the normal way e.g. configure the HelpPageConfig.cs to point to the correct xml file. Build the project and checking the xml the summary details are not copied to it. Move the model into the same project then rebuild the summary comments are added and viewing in the help site shows the correct comments.
Is this a bug within the product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the details. I am not sure if I would call this a bug in Web API as it does not inherently depend on an xml file for documentation. For example, If you have installed HelpPage, you would notice a file called `XmlDocumentationProvider.cs` under `Areas\HelpPage`. 
This implementation of provider looks at single xml file.

For your scenario, you could create a custom implementation of `IDocumentationProvider` & `IModelDocumentationProvider` in which based on the C# type, you can look at different xml documentation files. You could reuse most of the code in the default XmlDocumentationProvider.

Comment: Ouch. Seems like a lot of work required for what I think lots of other people would be expecting from the helppage. I have setup my model project now to generate the xml documentation file so now just a case of trying to merge togeather and get the XmlDocumentProvider.cs to work

Answer (score 13):

You may use the following implementation of IDocumentationProvider that is a copy of XmlDocumentationProvider with minor modifications.

Usage example in HelpPageConfig.cs:

```
config.SetDocumentationProvider(new MultipleXmlDocumentationProvider(
            HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/bin/App.DataContracts.XML"),
            HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/bin/App.Controllers.XML")));
```

MultipleXmlDocumentationProvider class:

```
public class MultipleXmlDocumentationProvider : IDocumentationProvider, IModelDocumentationProvider
{
    private IList<XPathNavigator> _documentNavigators;
    private const string TypeExpression = "/doc/members/member[@name='T:{0}']";
    private const string MethodExpression = "/doc/members/member[@name='M:{0}']";
    private const string PropertyExpression = "/doc/members/member[@name='P:{0}']";
    private const string FieldExpression = "/doc/members/member[@name='F:{0}']";
    private const string ParameterExpression = "param[@name='{0}']";

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="XmlDocumentationProvider"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="documentPaths">List of physical paths to XML documents.</param>
    public MultipleXmlDocumentationProvider(params string[] documentPaths)
    {
        if (!documentPaths.Any())
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("documentPaths");
        }

        var documents = documentPaths.Where(p => File.Exists(p)).ToList();

        _documentNavigators = documents.Select(p => new XPathDocument(p).CreateNavigator()).ToList();
    }

    public string GetDocumentation(HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)
    {
        XPathNavigator typeNode = GetTypeNode(controllerDescriptor.ControllerType);
        return GetTagValue(typeNode, "summary");
    }

    public virtual string GetDocumentation(HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        XPathNavigator methodNode = GetMethodNode(actionDescriptor);
        return GetTagValue(methodNode, "summary");
    }

    public virtual string GetDocumentation(HttpParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor)
    {
        ReflectedHttpParameterDescriptor reflectedParameterDescriptor = parameterDescriptor as ReflectedHttpParameterDescriptor;
        if (reflectedParameterDescriptor != null)
        {
            XPathNavigator methodNode = GetMethodNode(reflectedParameterDescriptor.ActionDescriptor);
            if (methodNode != null)
            {
                string parameterName = reflectedParameterDescriptor.ParameterInfo.Name;
                XPathNavigator parameterNode = methodNode.SelectSingleNode(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, ParameterExpression, parameterName));
                if (parameterNode != null)
                {
                    return parameterNode.Value.Trim();
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public string GetResponseDocumentation(HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        XPathNavigator methodNode = GetMethodNode(actionDescriptor);
        return GetTagValue(methodNode, "returns");
    }

    public string GetDocumentation(MemberInfo member)
    {
        string memberName = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}.{1}", GetTypeName(member.DeclaringType), member.Name);
        string expression = member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field ? FieldExpression : PropertyExpression;
        string selectExpression = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, expression, memberName);
        var propertyNode = _documentNavigators.Select(n => n.SelectSingleNode(selectExpression)).FirstOrDefault(n => n != null);
        return GetTagValue(propertyNode, "summary");
    }

    public string GetDocumentation(Type type)
    {
        XPathNavigator typeNode = GetTypeNode(type);
        return GetTagValue(typeNode, "summary");
    }

    private XPathNavigator GetMethodNode(HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor reflectedActionDescriptor = actionDescriptor as ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor;
        if (reflectedActionDescriptor != null)
        {
            string selectExpression = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, MethodExpression, GetMemberName(reflectedActionDescriptor.MethodInfo));
            return _documentNavigators.Select(n => n.SelectSingleNode(selectExpression)).FirstOrDefault(n => n != null);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static string GetMemberName(MethodInfo method)
    {
        string name = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}.{1}", GetTypeName(method.DeclaringType), method.Name);
        ParameterInfo[] parameters = method.GetParameters();
        if (parameters.Length != 0)
        {
            string[] parameterTypeNames = parameters.Select(param => GetTypeName(param.ParameterType)).ToArray();
            name += String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "({0})", String.Join(",", parameterTypeNames));
        }

        return name;
    }

    private static string GetTagValue(XPathNavigator parentNode, string tagName)
    {
        if (parentNode != null)
        {
            XPathNavigator node = parentNode.SelectSingleNode(tagName);
            if (node != null)
            {
                return node.Value.Trim();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private XPathNavigator GetTypeNode(Type type)
    {
        string controllerTypeName = GetTypeName(type);
        string selectExpression = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, TypeExpression, controllerTypeName);
        return _documentNavigators.Select(n => n.SelectSingleNode(selectExpression)).FirstOrDefault(n => n != null);
    }

    private static string GetTypeName(Type type)
    {
        string name = type.FullName;
        if (type.IsGenericType)
        {
            // Format the generic type name to something like: Generic{System.Int32,System.String}
            Type genericType = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
            Type[] genericArguments = type.GetGenericArguments();
            string genericTypeName = genericType.FullName;

            // Trim the generic parameter counts from the name
            genericTypeName = genericTypeName.Substring(0, genericTypeName.IndexOf('`'));
            string[] argumentTypeNames = genericArguments.Select(t => GetTypeName(t)).ToArray();
            name = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}{{{1}}}", genericTypeName, String.Join(",", argumentTypeNames));
        }
        if (type.IsNested)
        {
            // Changing the nested type name from OuterType+InnerType to OuterType.InnerType to match the XML documentation syntax.
            name = name.Replace("+", ".");
        }

        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just added you custom provider and it works like a charm!!
Kudo++ to you

Comment: Excellent. Just an additional note - in the project properties one can set the xml documentation file path of the 2nd dll as relative path, so all xml docs end up in one nice location. No extra build event needed.

Comment: This answer, together with most of http://codethug.com/2015/01/16/web-api-deep-dive-customizing-auto-generated-documentation-part-1-of-6/ got me up and running.  Thanks very much.